# codeigniter validate login error

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

i have a login method but it doesn't seems to work correctly. For example if i try to login with a username that exists in the database and the password of another user, i can successfully login. Can someone spot the error in my code?

**Controller:**

```
 public function login(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name_login', 'Utilizator', 'required|callback_validate_login|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_login', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_login','login esuat');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '*');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

        $this->render('login');
    }
    else {
        // user successful login

        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('name_login'),
            'is_logged_in' => 1

        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        $this->load->view('homeview',$data);
    }
}

    public function validate_login(){
         $username = $this->input->post('user_login');
         $pass  = $this->input->post('password_login');

        if ($this->homemodel->login($username,$pass)){
            return true;// form validation passed, u are now logged in
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
    public function login($user, $pass)
{

    $query = $this->db->get_where('login', array('username' => $user, 'password' => $pass));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($query->result());
    echo '</pre>';

    if ($query->num_rows() === 1) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open('home/login') ?>
<label for="user">Username</label>  
<input type="text"  class="createform" name="user_login"  value="<?php echo set_value('name_login'); ?> " />  
<?php echo form_error('name_login') . '<br>'; ?>  
<label for="pass">Password</label>  
<input type="text" class="createform" name="password_login" value="<?php echo set_value('password_login'); ?> " />  
<?php echo form_error('password_login') . '<br>'; ?>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />  
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure the callback to validate_login is firing?

Answer (score 1):

Oh,my bad, found the error :  the username input name in the view file is "user_login" and in the controller i wrote 'name_login':
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('name_login',...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the session data to `is_logged_in` just on successful form submission:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

    $this->render('login');
}
else {
    // user successful login

    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('name_login'),
        'is_logged_in' => 1

    );
```

You need to validate the user first.

I would try something like:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

    $this->render('login');
}
else {

    $results = $this->validate_login();
    // user successful login
    if ($results){
       $data = array(
           'username' => $this->input->post('name_login'),
           'is_logged_in' => 1
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($data);

    $this->load->view('homeview',$data);
}
   else {
       redirect('login');
   }
}
```

Does that make sense? It doesn't look like you were actually checking or calling the `validate_login()` method.

Comment: validate_login() is a callback function . If it returns true then the form_validation runs

Comment: Ah I see, I did not see that!